# Split column value in relation to other columns per group

Tags: r, datatable, formatting

so i have a data table like:

[image]

I need to break value1 in the relations of value2 per id-group

Index 1,2,3 are a group cause of the same id -> the relation of value2 in the group is 0.7((14+2+4)/14)
So value1 needs to be 7000 -> index 2: value1=1000, index 2: value2=2000 -> sum=10000

The datatable needs to look like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can try it this way:

```
df <- data.frame(index = 1:6,
                 id = c("abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"),
                 value = c(10000,10000,10000,50000, 20000, 20000),
                 value2 = c(14,2,4,6,3,3))

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value = value*(value2/sum(value2)))
         

  index id    value value2
  <int> <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 abc    7000     14
2     2 abc    1000      2
3     3 abc    2000      4
4     4 def   50000      6
5     5 ghi   10000      3
6     6 ghi   10000      3
```

**EDIT**: Here is the extension you mentioned.

```
df <- data.frame(index = 1:6,
                 id = c("abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "ghi", "ghi"),
                 value = c(10000,10000,10000,50000, 20000, 20000),
                 value2 = c(14,NA,4,6,NA, NA))


df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(!all(is.na(value2)) & is.na(value2), 0,
                         value2)) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value2),
                        value/length(value2),
                        value*(value2/sum(value2))))

  index id     value value2
  <int> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 abc    7778.     14
2     2 abc       0       0
3     3 abc    2222.      4
4     4 def   50000       6
5     5 ghi   10000      NA
6     6 ghi   10000      NA
```

Comment: On top of that its possible, column "value 2" has no data. If all Value2 of an id-group have no data, value1 should be split in same parts (ex. 50:50 with 2 ids). If one or more value2 have values, then other id's of the group with no data in value2 should be treatened like value2=0, do you have an idea how to do that?